# Как сделать подстановку в JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Как вставить значение в JavaScript-код, если оно уже занято? Короче есть переменная

```
id=107;
```

А дальше в коде идет так (выборка всех параграфов по `id`):

```
$('p[id=id]').text('New value');
```

Пробовал `id` поменять на другую переменную, но ничего не вышло. Так как все-таки правильно вставлять значения в `JavaScript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('p[id='+id+']').text('New value');
```

Не?

И еще:

Цифровые ID ставить не принято. Долго объяснять почему, просто переменные такого рода обычно начинаются с буквы.

И ваш код - не jquery) есть

```
$('#'+id).text('New value');
```

Comment: Спсасибо )